# Thymeleaf th:if expression not evaluating true

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, templating, thymeleaf

I am trying to evaluate an expression with two strings, its evaluating to true as well, but when used within the th:if its not working as expected.

the below code is what I am trying

```
<div th:with="cntx=${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI()}">
   <li th:each="obj : ${list}" th:with="path=${obj.path}"
                    th:if="${path == cntx}">
    <span th:text="${obj.title}"></span>
   </li>
</div>
```

The context for the above code,

I have a list of objects which contain the link that has to be displayed in one of the objects. I am trying to a string equality with th:if, but the expression here ${path == cntx} is failing for some reason and not showing on the final rendered page.

I even checked the path and URI values which is equal i.e /test for path and /test for cntx, evaluating to true if I print it out using the th:text. Quite strange behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the if is evaluated before the `th:with`. You could try :

```
<th:block th:each="obj : ${list}" th:with="path=${obj.path}">
  <li  th:if="${path == cntx}">...</li>
</th:block>
```

However, for me, it would have print some kind of useful exception (like: variable path not found).

Comment: Thanks for the advice.. Worked like a charm. :)